Detecting difference between EOA and a contract with regard to smart wallets
I'm using the assembly code given at the URL below to check if an address is an EOA or a contract:
How does a contract find out if another address is a contract?
However, I'm not sure how this will work with a smart wallet. Will it be detected as an EOA or a contract?

Smart Wallets are contracts, so it will detect them as contracts.

It just checks code size, it's a naïve test. A smart wallet has code so would as Zartaj, mentions be classified as a contract.

This test will also say EOA for a contract that is mid-constructor (i.e. a contract calling your contract from within the constructor will show 0 code, so EOA)
